# Programmatically modify my Internet Explorer toolbar

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-c++

How to programmatically modify my Internet Explorer toolbar button? I am currently using visual c++.

Comment: Please provide a more detailed description of your issue.  Is your toolbar button on your own toolbar or is it a command bar button hosted in IE's toolbar?  How do you want to modify it?

Comment: It is my own toolbar. It has the *.rc, *.rgs files too. I found out that, the declaration/definition for the features of the button is inside the files, but don't know how to modify it in run time mode. Eg: change the button's *.ico from my IF-THEN line.

Comment: I have 2 *.ico inside my project. I would like the button to change its *.ico based on the conditions I set inside my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your own toolbar, and you want to change the state of a button (e.g. the icon, the text, the tooltip) then you just merely have to send it [the correct messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787433(v=VS.85).aspx).

However, my psychic powers tell me that you've created a Command Bar button by following [these steps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753588(v=VS.85).aspx).  In that case, the answer is: you can't.  In IE6 and IE7 you could use FindWindow() and the [Toolbar API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff486067(v=VS.85).aspx) to eventually send the right window messages to your button to get it to change its icon / text.  However, in IE8 that toolbar button lives in a different Window and a different *Integrity Level* than your extension.  So you can't send it messages.

So, my advice to you is to write your own toolbar plug-in, or give up trying to alter your icon's state.

Comment: Yep. I followed the steps inside the website. I'm currently doing it for IE7/below only. IE8 I found out very difficult.

Comment: or is there any way to make the button invisible/visible during run time?

Comment: There are no practical, advisable or supported ways.